# How to align multiple columns based on highlighted values in the rows in excel

Tags: excel

I have an excel sheet with multiple columns and want to align a few of the columns with the same name, e.g. column_ABC, based on the values highlighted in yellow colour. Each column has one highlighted value, so bringing all the highlighted values face to face (same row). An example image has been attached with the input data and the required output data.
Note: After the results, the values in each column will shift either above or below.

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: @Mech, I am sorry. Can't you see it? I think I have already posted it. One image with original data and required.

Comment: Your question doesn't have the VBA tag. Are you ok with using VBA to fix your issue?

Comment: @Mech Sorry, only excel if possible. Otherwise, VBA may be an option left.

Comment: I know you can sort by highlighted color using Excel but not in the way you want. A loop to find the highlighted then sort it might be your only option.

Comment: Be sure to accept an answer to close the post and to show others the solution if they have a similar issue. :)

Comment: @Mech Okay. Thank you for your solution. I am still waiting for an easier solution. In case no more replies, I will go ahead with it then.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a VBA option. I've commented it to help with understanding. This will work if more columns are added. If the column has no yellow highlight, it will be skipped.

```
Sub test()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim lRow, lCol, iRow, iCol As Long
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Dim ReSort As Object: Set ReSort = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    ' Find first empty cell in column A
    lRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    ' Find first empty column in row 2
    lCol = ws.Cells(2, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    ' Loop through each filled column and row
    For iCol = 1 To lCol
        For iRow = 2 To lRow
            ' Find yellow
            If (Cells(iRow, iCol).Interior.Color = 65535) Then
                ' Store location of yellow highlight
                ReSort(iCol) = iRow
                ' Move rows in columns other than the first
                If iCol > 1 Then
                    ws.Range(Cells(2, iCol), Cells(100, iCol)).Cut Destination:=ws.Cells(ReSort(1) - ReSort(iCol) + 2, iCol)
                End If
            End If
        Next iRow
    Next iCol
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```